# MySQL INSERT INTO query are too slow in C

Tags: mysql, sql, c, performance, insert

I need to put the data collected by a data acquisition system on a MySQL database through a C program.
I have 2 tables with 3 and 5 columns (and 1 foreign key for the second table).
Currently, it takes few minutes to put around 4000 values (it could be a lot more in the end) despite my pretty good computer (and the program would have to run on a crappy one).

Is there any way to make it faster ?

I know similar questions were posted, but the answers were too advanced for me.

Comment: Please post some code and table definitions.  Definitely seems too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you perhaps using a separate query for each row? Don't forget you can add multiple rows with a single query. So for example, instead of

```
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (4, 5, 6);
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (7, 8, 9);
```

you can issue a single query like this:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9);
```

Here are a couple of other optimizations that you could try:

#### Disable indexes

As you update a MySQL table, it will attempt to reconstruct the table's indexes after each insertion. For large insertions, it's more efficient to disable indexing temporarily while you're updating the table. To do this, send this query before you start the update:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` DISABLE KEYS;
```

and then re-enable indexing when you're done:

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` ENABLE KEYS;
```

#### Disable foreign key checks

Again, these can slow things up when working with large tables. Issue the command

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

to disable foreign key checks before you start modifying the table, and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

to re-enable these checks when you're done.

Comment: The first point is very valid but I don't necessarily agree with the 2nd and certainly not the 3rd. Disabling keys will mean the index will only get rebuilt once; if you are batching all inserts then you only have one query. Disabling foreign key checks only helps if you have foreign keys and if so then the consequences of potential loss of referential integrity is pretty high. Generally it is expected that if data is in a table and that table has foreign keys then it will have referential integrity; disabling foreign key checks breaks that implicit contract.

Comment: @abasterfield I wouldn't recommend disabling foreign key checks without being sure of the data's integrity. However, it can help speed things up when, for example, restoring a database from a backup that's known to be safe (which is often the case when performing large insertions like this). And yes, if all the insertions can be made with a single query, then disabling indexes would be redundant.

Comment: The problem is that I read the data from binary files without knowing the total number of entry. Plus, I don't know how to deal with sql query's max length